# Fortran: Pointer to an array which index start at 0

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

Here is my problem:

I declare a 3D array in a module and I allocate it with the first index starting from 0:

```
REAL*8, POINTER :: QALC(:,:,:)
ALLOCATE(QALC(0:N+1,NR+1,NLVL))
```

I have also a pointer which I want to point to the above array:

```
REAL*8, POINTER :: Q(:,:)
Q=>QALC(0:N+1,1:NR+1,L)
```

where L is an integer. The above code works but unfortunately the index of Q starts from 1 and not from 0! Is any way to make Q first index be 0?

Many thanks,
ilias

Comment: It's clunky but why not always subtract `1` when getting an element from Q? Like `Q(index - 1,dim2,dim3)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the bounds of `Q` in the pointer assignment:

```
Q(0:,:) => QALC(:,:,L)
```

Comment: I have tried that but I got error in the compile:
"error #6731: Object is not a pointer object. ". I google it and unfortunately I found that it may be a bug in the compiler (Intel 11.0): https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/295038. Any other solution? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Note that I should have put `Q(0:,1:)`.  I'll edit that in later when I think I'll do a more substantive answer.

Comment: In particular, my first attempt was wrong: you don't want bounds remapping (which is what it was).

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the error "Object is not a pointer object". Is there any way to do it after (or before) the "=>" command? Thank you again.

Comment: If that's with the correction in the comment, then I'm afraid I can't help: I can't reproduce the problem with my setup so there's no guarantee that any work-around would be suitable against the same problem.